# Camel-Beanio not finding Bean Class

Tags: apache-camel, bean-io, apache-servicemix

I'm using apache-servicemix-7.0.0, and using camel-beanio with it (2.16.4).

So I have defined a route that calls beanio to parse a file.

However the Class that the records map to is in an external jar.

I have tried to wrap this external jar using:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/UrlHandlers-Wrap.html

and it makes it available.

But when I deploy my camel blueprint.xml it still throws:

"2017-05-24 15:57:51,566 | ERROR | mix-7.0.0/deploy | BlueprintCamelContext            | 40 - org.apache.camel. 
camel-blueprint - 2.16.4 | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(_context1) due Invalid record 'r 
ecord', in stream 'REALITY_FILE': Invalid bean class 'za.co.sci.core.shared.RealityFileRecordModel' 
org.beanio.BeanIOConfigurationException: Invalid record 'record', in stream 'REALITY_FILE': Invalid bean class 
 'za.co.sci.core.shared.RealityFileRecordModel' 
        at org.beanio.internal.compiler.ProcessorSupport.process(ProcessorSupport.java:93)[232:org.beanio:2.1. 
0] 
.... 
... 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: za.co.sci.core.shared.RealityFileRecordModel not found by ESB-POC 
 [257] 
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1 
574)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar:]

" 
My blue print attached, and camel mapping xml attached

Any ideas how to make camel route find this class?

Thanks,
Jose

Comment: How do you add the dependency? If it is through maven, did you try importing package containing mapping class?

Comment: Hi like I mentioned above I used the wrap:mvn: command. I can see it on the console as Active. If I do a package:imports and grep my package I can see it there. I've also tried using https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.4.1/html/Console_Reference/files/ESBDev-DynamicImport.html but nothing yet

Comment: Make sure your own bundle with the Camel xml route imports that package `za.co.sci.core.shared` and other packages you need